# How can I resolve this error? SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")

Tags: raspbian, python-3, software-installation, internet

I can't figure this out. I've now researched and tried for hours but I can't solve this so hear me out.

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and installed Raspbian OS on it.
Raspbian came with Python2.X and Python 3.7 preinstalled, however I need Python 3.8+ so I followed [this tutorial](https://raspberrytips.com/install-latest-python-raspberry-pi/) to install Python 3.10 on it.
Now whenever I try to install any package with pip I get a `WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.`, followed by multiple failing tries to reach pypi.org or piwheels.org and finally the error stated in the title.
I've tried `python3.10 -m pip install`, `pip3 install` and every other possible python and pip version with the same result.
I've tried to reinstall pyOpenSSL, which was stupid because I uninstalled it and then couldn't reinstall it because I got the same error. I then manually downloaded pyOpenSSL and its dependencies to my local machine, zipped them, moved them to my pi and installed it there locally which worked. However that didn't change anything either. It still tells me SSL weren't available when trying to install any package via pip.

The only thing I could find on this is [this article](https://debugah.com/solved-pip-install-cv2-error-error-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-cv2-from-versions-none-16880/) along with the similar ones linked below it.
However, I have never before heard of that site, it's powered by wordpress, it doesn't have comments or anything suggesting that site to be remotely trust-worthy. Seems sketchy, and the "solution" seems like a workaround by simply not using https altogether which is not what I want.
Other than that I found about 30 different chinese sites which quote the same error. However everything else on those sites is in chinese and I can't read chinese. I also doubt that the solution is only available in chinese.

The complete lack of results online suggests to me that this is a problem nobody except me ever had and I'm an idiot who did something super obvious wrong but I just can't figure out what.

Any help would be appreciated because I don't know how to move on from here.

I'm happy to provide additional information if I missed anything important.

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what **YOU** did - links to a tutorial are ambiguous at best.

The ONLY way to install on Buster is from source.

NOTE Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye comes with 3.9 so you could try linking to the Bullseye archive for a Pi compatible version or try a install of Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye beta.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely not an idiot. I'm experiencing the exact same issue with any version of python I install on my pi manually.

After following basically the same procedure to install 3.10, I was just trying to install virtualenv and got the

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, 
however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

error. So I installed 3.9 and got the same error. Tried pipping any other package and got the same error. Then I switched back to the original 3.7.3 that came with Raspian and

```
python -m pip install virtualenv
```

worked just fine.

Not sure which ssl module the manual install wants or how to install it, but I'm working on it and when I figure it out, I'll post it here.

Edit 1. [It looks as though the opensll that is on the Raspberry Pi is not compatible with newer python versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56552390/how-to-fix-ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-in-centos).

The recommendation is to install the new openssl and then rebuild python with a flag pointing to your new better local version of opensll.

The second option, which is the one I'm opting for, is @Milliways recommendation of [updating the entire os to Bullseye](https://peyanski.com/how-to-upgrade-raspberry-pi-buster-to-bullseye/). Not only did this seem like the easier route, it also seemed like this would eliminate problems in the future as well since it would update a ton of out of date packages.

It's not done upgrading, but I will check back in for sure if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried also a few things on my pi. checked that openssl is installed and up-to-date. Apparently there are a few options on the configure command used during the python build from sources. After setting the ssl folder and tried to enable ssl during build, the following settings helped resolve the issue for me (assuming they are executed within the python 3.10.x sources folder):

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --with-ssl-default-suites=openssl 
make altinstall
```